# Python: right way to build a string by joining a smaller substring N times

Tags: python, string

What is the right "pythonic" way to do the following operation?

```
s = ""
for i in xrange(0, N):
    s += "0101"
```

E.g. in Perl it would be: `$s = "0101" x $N`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nearly the same as Perl:

```
"0101" * N
```

Answer (score 2):

The most Pythonic way would be

```
s = "0101" * N
```

Other methods include:

- use `StringIO`, which is a file-like object for building strings:

  ```
  from StringIO import StringIO
  ```
- use `"".join`; that is

  ```
  `"".join("0101" for i in xrange(N)`
  ```
- use your algorithm. In an unoptimised world this is less good, because it is quadratic in the length of the string. I believe recent versions of Python actually optimise this so that it is linear, but I can't find a reference for that.

Comment: Let's not confuse the issue. After all, isn't the whole idea to get away from Perl-esque TIMTOWDI? :)